# Android SDK-Get specific contacts from contact list

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to query the contacts table to get all the contacts of a specific name, for example all the contacts with first name "George"

At the moment I get all the contacts with this

Cursor contactsCursor = managedQuery(contactData,
                        null, null, null, null);

Any help is appriciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME + " = ?", 
            new String[] { "George" }, null);
```